# Not understanding use of new keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, new-operator

The code snippet below is from 'Javascript Web Applications' by O'Reilly.  In it, the author explains that using the `new` keyword ordinarily returns a `this` context, unless you specifically return something else-- below, he's returning ' a function that would set up a new class', in his words (pg 7):

```
var Class = function(){
    var klass = function(){
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    klass.prototype.init = function(){};
    return klass;
};

var Person = new Class;

Person.prototype.init = function(){
    // Called on Person instantiation
};

// Usage:
var person = new Person;
```

I'm not following this.  What does returning `klass` do here?  in the case of `var Person = new Class`, am I not getting a new Class object, but rather, some function that can create a Class?  That's what I'm reading from the text but it's confusing to me.

Comment: It's an implementation of inheritance.  Person "extends" Class. Both Class and klass are class definitions, the JavaScript way. Returning klass creates a separate prototype every time you call new Class. That means a new subclass every time. The example shows how you can override a "virtual function" by modifying a prototype. If you created another subclass, it would't be affected, e.g., Thing = new Class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before getting where he's going, the first step is getting `this`.

There are three things `this` can typically point to.
If you have a function which is a property of an object:

```
var Bob = {
    name : "Bob",
    say  : function () { console.log(this.name); }
};

Bob.say(); // "Bob"
```

In this case, `this` points to whatever object owns the property  (whatever is one-dot ahead, at the exact moment the function is called)

```
var say = Bob.say; // passing the function to a variable
var Sam = { name : "Sam" };
Sam.say = Bob.say; // passing the function to an object's property

say(); // undefined -- not what you were expecting
Sam.say(); // "Sam"
```

So `this` is decided at the last possible second.

Functions also have properties of their own, like objects.
Two of these are functions called `.call` and `.apply` and they allow you to run the function, but tell the function exactly what `this` is.

Remember how `say();` didn't work on its own?

```
var say = Bob.say;
say.call(Bob); // "Bob" -- hooray!
```

The next part of `this` is the one we're most used to in object-oriented languages; using `this` along with `new` to make a new instance of a class:

```
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.say = function () { console.log(this.name); };
};

var bob = new Person("Bob");
bob.say(); // "Bob"
```

Basically, inside of this constructor function (or any function, as constructors aren't special in JS), the function starts by checking if `new` was called.
If it was, set `this` to a brand new object, regardless of whether it's part of an object:

```
var Creatures = {};
Creatures.Person = Person;

Creatures.Person("Bob"); // `this` === Creatures
Creatures.name; // "Bob" -- whoops
var bob = new Creatures.Person("Bob");
bob.say(); // "Bob", yay!
```

So it's like the function is saying `if (new) { this = {}; }` at the top of the function.

I said there were three possibilities.
The third is that `this === window`
If you use a function where `this` isn't an object (either through call/apply, or as a property of an object) and `new` was not used to make a new object, then `this` points at `window`.
That is why `say();` did not work on its own, before; `window.say();` is the equivalent.

Back to `new` for a second -- `new` does a couple of other things.
Namely, it sets the value of the object's constructor:

```
var bob = new Person();
bob instanceof Person;  // true
```

It also gives objects made from that constructor access to the `prototype` object, which all instances share.

So now, look at what's going on inside of Class/Klass:
We're creating a `new Class();` object.
Inside of the `Class` function, `this = {};` (because of `new`).
Then, we're making a new "constructor" function, `klass`.

Then, we're setting the prototyped `init` function, which we `.apply` to any new `this` (in the `klass`, at the time a new instance is called).

Then we're returning the klass.

klass is actually what you're calling when you make a new Class

And when you call for a new object of a class, klass is being run.

Hope that helps with `new` and `this` and `.call` and `Class/klass`.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation.  I do have some leftover confusion regarding the last bit and what's happening with `klass` when `new` is called.  You say that when `new` is called that when I make a new class that `klass` is actually being called, and not simply returned?

Comment: So it's actually both. But in two steps. For the purposes of this exact example of Class/klass, the first `new` makes no difference. More on that, later. There is one more step being done here than usual. Ignore the difference between `var class = new Class();` and `var class = Class();` - they both return `klass`. So `class === klass`. `var Person = new Class();` and `var Person = klass;` are the same thing, here, for all intent and purpose. When you use the `.prototype` in conjunction with `new`, each new instance gets access to the same prototype functions/properties. `.init` is running ...

Comment: ...each time you ask for a new `Person`, because of the way `klass` is wired. You make a `Person` class, which you build from the class-building `Class`, then you define your prototype. The way `klass` works, it calls that function at creation of each new instance, passing in the new `this` as well as the arguments you passed to the class.  `var bob = new Person("Bob");` will go through `klass` and call `this.init("Bob");` on its way through.

Comment: @Norguard-- again, thank you.  In your comment, when you say 'class-building `Class`', you're referring to `klass` I take it?  (just want to be 100% certain.)
So in summary, calling `new Class` returns an instance of `klass`, with an `init` method wired in and ready to be called whenever `new` is called thereafter (ex: `var person = new Person` runs the `init` method.)
By overriding the `klass.prototype`'s version of `init` with a `Person`-specific one, calling `new Person` calls that version of `init`.  I may have missed a nuance or two but I believe that's the gist?

Comment: Yes, that's what's going on. You've got it. The initial stumbling-block here is that by returning `klass` the result doesn't make instances, but makes a rewired constructor function, which *does take* ***new***. Now, bear in mind that you could start messing around with the inners of `Class`, before the return, which would provide functions/vars which any subclass would have access to, through closure. But none of the `prototype` methods would have access, just the functions defined within the class, itself, which is where the further utility of this format falls down a little.

Comment: @Norguard-- thanks again.  I hate to ask, as this may be 100% obvious, but would you know the advantage in `klass` of using `this.init.apply(this, arguments);` instead of `this.init(arguments);`?  It makes sense in your example with `say.call(Bob)`, but it seems like in the case of `klass` it's equivalent to `this.call(this)`-- what's the point of all that indirection?

Comment: Again, it's one of those things that nobody needs to know, until they get under the hood. `.apply` and `.call` both make a function run, but force `this` to be whatever you pass it. So the difference is in the arguments. `function setPos3D (x, y, z) { this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z; }` now we can either call it like `var vector = {}; setPos3D.call(vector, 1, 2, 3); or setPos3D.apply(vector, [1,2,3]);`. Catch the difference? Call makes you type out all of the arguments by hand, and apply takes an array of arguments (and will fill the function properly, from the start of the array)...

Comment: ...I'm sure by now you're catching the "aha": if we're trying to send arguments from the current function into a `.call` where we know the function needs 5 arguments, then that's fine: our `.call` can have six arguments (`this` + the known 5). But what if we're coming from a function and we don't know how many arguments there are? Or don't know how many the other function will take, et cetera. Because `prototype.init could be retrofit to anything, how can klass know how many arguments there are and in which order? Hence `.apply` . That fix looks sloppy, but it's better than JS before.

Comment: I see.  So the call to `.apply` in `klass` is a form of future-proofing against subsequent rewrites of `init` in subclasses.  Makes sense, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In javascript the `new` keyword implicitly returns `this`.

When you have `function Foo () {}` and apply `new Foo`, under the hood javascript does this `function Foo () { return this; }`.  He is overwriting the way javascript's `new` works by explicitly returning a different object (the klass object).

Look at this example.

```
function Foo () { this.name = "foo"; };

function Bar () {
    return new Foo; 
};

var bar = new Bar;  // bar is now a Foo, because of the explicit return.

bar.name //=> 'foo'
```

If you can follow that you can follow what he is doing.

When you say `var Person = new Class`, it is actually returning the `klass` function and storing it in the `Person` variable (pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Following the author's logic:

> using the `new` keyword ordinarily returns a `this` context,
>   **unless** you specifically return something else

If he/she is correct, then the following code:

```
var Class = function(){
    var klass = function(){
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    klass.prototype.init = function(){};
    return klass;
};
```

Does not define a "class" class; instead, it defines a "base" that, when `new`ed, instead of returning an *instance*, will return a privately defined *class* that, when `new`ed, will be guaranteed to run the `init()` method (`this.init.apply(this)`).

By that manner, when

```
var Person = new Class;
```

you are creating a new **class** named `Person`, that follows the constraints and behaviors (if any) defined as `klass`, inside `Class` (kind of look like `extend`/`inherit` in "real" OOP).

So the following code

```
Person.prototype.init = function(){
// Called on Person instantiation
};
```

is actually defining a "constructor" for **class** `Person`.

**Edit**:

Sorry for not coming up with proper words and sentences yesterday. I'm bad at expressing.

If you're comfortable with OOP, you can **imagine** that, `Class` is rather an interface/abstract/virtual class, and when you `new Class`, instead of *creating an instance*, you're rather extending/inheriting/implementing the behavior privately/virtually defined inside `Class`.

The `klass.prototype.init=function(){};` kind of like a JS's way of abstract/virtual function, and by combining `this.init.apply(this)`, you can, at may level, imagine it a constructor.

Comment: Thank you.  Am I correct in assuming that Person.prototype.init 'overrides' the definition set in klass.prototype.init?

Comment: @larryq Yes. And in OOP's word, you can imagine `klass.prototype.init` defined inside `Class` is a virtual/abstract constructor. Although in JS you don't always have to re-implement ("override") it, you are encouraged to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, here `var Person = new Class;` the `new` keyword is used only to fire the `Class` function, so basically you could use like this `var Person = Class();` and it will have the same result